# slideshow image, video with jquery cycle

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create slideshow with image and video.  the slideshow is running, 
but  when video is running, slideshow go to the next slide, because jquery timeout..
I want the video finished first before go to the next slide, even the video need 5 minutes for running.

Any one can help me ?

this is the script..

```
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myslides').cycle({
    fit: 1, pause: 2
});
});
</script>




<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

</head>
<body>

<?php

  echo " < table border=0 align=center width=1280 bgcolor=#FA9C56 CLASS='deepsea' >";
  echo "< tr height=65><td><img src=images/logo.png width=50 height=50 border=0>< /td>
  < td align=left width=100%>< font class=fakultas>< font color=#F3F60F>< strong>Fakultas Ilmu Sosial & Politik < /strong></ font>< /td>< /tr>";
  echo "< /table>";
?>
< div id="myslides">
< ?php

include "config/koneksi.php";
$tanggalku = date("Y-m-d");

$cek_query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pengumuman a JOIN pengumuman_detail b ON     a.id_pengumuman=b.id_pengumuman and     deadline_pengumuman > '$tanggalku'");

while ($rs=mysql_fetch_array($cek_query))
{


  echo "< table border=0 align=center width=1200>";

  echo "< tr>";
  echo "< td align=center  width=100%>";
  echo "< font class=judul><font color=#111111><strong>".$rs[judul_pengumuman]."    </strong>< /font>";
  echo "< /td>";
  echo "< /tr>";
  echo "< tr>";
  echo "< td width=1200>";  
  echo '< tr>< td>< hr class="style2">< /td>< /tr>';
  echo "< /td>";
  echo "< /tr>";

  echo "< tr>";

  if ( $rs[status]=='F')
  {
  echo "< td  align=center>";
  echo "< img src='foto/".$rs[file_upload]."'  border=2 >";
  echo "< /td>";
  }
  elseif ( $rs[status]=='V')
  {
   echo "< td  align=center>";
  ?>

        < OBJECT ID="MediaPlayer" WIDTH=320 HEIGHT=331 CLASSID="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" STANDBY="Loading Windows Media Player components..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject">
        <  PARAM NAME="FileName" VALUE="video-filename.wmv">
    <  PARAM name="ShowControls" VALUE="true">
    <  param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
    <  PARAM name="ShowDisplay" VALUE="true">
    <  PARAM name="autostart" VALUE="true">
    <  EMBED TYPE="application/x-mplayer2" SRC="ABBG.avi" NAME="MediaPlayer" WIDTH=820 HEIGHT=451 ShowControls="0" 
    ShowStatusBar="1" ShowDisplay="1" autostart="1"> </EMBED>
    </OBJECT> 

  < ?php
        echo "< /td>";
  }
  else
  {
  echo "< td width=1200 align=center>";
  echo " ".$rs[isi_pengumuman_detail]."";
  echo "< /td>";
  }


  echo "< /tr>";


  echo "< /table>";
}

?>


</div>
```

Comment: i don't think, if it is not possible to detect the exact video buffering time because its depending on the internet speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('#myslides').cycle('toggle');` to toggle the slideshow on and off. You can use the `after: mycallback` option to detect if the slide that's being shown is a video. if it is, pause the cycle, start the video.

Finally, you need to find a way to dispatch an even when the video is complete **OR** if the user overrides it by going to the next slide. In that situation, you call `$('#myslides').cycle('toggle');` again to turn the slideshow back on.

The easiest way to pick up on a video event would be to use a player like jwplayer which has support for those events. It will also be nicer for your visitors.